# How to convert a list of number ranges with hyphens and commas in single values

Tags: python, excel, text

I have a list of numbers formatted like in the example below:

```
3074
88, 3074
1935, 3478-3480
3074, 3478-3479
27015-27030, 27036-27037
4380, 27000-27031, 27036
```

Basically, this is a collection of ports and port intervals.
I would like to convert this list in a one dimensional array, like for instance:

```
3074
88
3074
1935
3478
3479
3480
...
```

Basically, I want a single column but with repeated values in order to retain the information about the frequency of the number showing in the list.

I preferably would like to do this in Excel or in Python.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Your example is not a list. Do you mean that it is one long string, or one string for each line? Format it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Python solution.

```
data = """3074
88, 3074
1935, 3478-3480
3074, 3478-3479
27015-27030, 27036-27037
4380, 27000-27031, 27036"""
delimiters = "\n\r\t,"
for d in delimiters:
    data = data.replace(d, ' ')

lines = data.split(' ')
numbers = []
i = 0
for line in lines:
    if line == '':
        continue
    elif '-' in line:
        t = line.split('-')
        numbers += range(int(t[0]), int(t[1]) + 1)
    else:
        numbers.append(int(line))
```

> Out: 
>   [3074,
>    88,
>    3074,
>    1935,
>    3478,
>    3479,
>    3480,
>    3074,
>    3478,
>    3479,
>    27015,
>    27016,
>    27017,
>    27018,
>    27019,
>    27020,
>    27021,
>    27022,
>    27023,
>    27024,
>    27025,
>    27026,
>    27027,
>    27028,
>    27029,
>    27030,
>    27036,
>    27037,
>    4380,
>    27000,
>    27001,
>    27002,
>    27003,
>    27004,
>    27005,
>    27006,
>    27007,
>    27008,
>    27009,
>    27010,
>    27011,
>    27012,
>    27013,
>    27014,
>    27015,
>    27016,
>    27017,
>    27018,
>    27019,
>    27020,
>    27021,
>    27022,
>    27023,
>    27024,
>    27025,
>    27026,
>    27027,
>    27028,
>    27029,
>    27030,
>    27031,
>    27036]

Answer (score 1):

A Javascript Solution

```js
  const findQuestionIds=(str)=>{
  
    let commaSeparated=str?.split(",")??str;

    let questionIds=[];
    let hyphenatedRange=[];

    console.log(commaSeparated);

     commaSeparated?.map((data)=>{

      console.log(data);

      if(data.toString().includes("-")) hyphenatedRange.push(data);
      else questionIds.push(parseInt(data));
    })

    hyphenatedRange.map((range)=>{
      
      range= range.split("-");
      let start= range[0];
      let end= range[1];

      for(let i=start; i<=end; i++){
        questionIds.push(parseInt(i))
      }

    })

    console.log("questionIds", questionIds);
    setSelectedQuestionIds(questionIds);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel VBA solution is as below, using Chip Pearson's fantastic SplitEx Function.

```
Sub remove_spclChar()
Dim rng As Range, l As Variant, i As Long
Dim ctr As Long: ctr = 1
For Each rng In Range("A1:A6")
l = SplitEx(rng.Value, True, ",", "-")
For i = LBound(l) To UBound(l)
Range("B" & ctr).Value = l(i)
ctr = ctr + 1
 Next i
Next
 End Sub
 Function SplitEx(ByVal InString As String, IgnoreDoubleDelmiters As _
 Boolean, _
    ParamArray Delims() As Variant) As String()
 Dim Arr() As String
 Dim Ndx As Long
 Dim N As Long

If Len(InString) = 0 Then
    SplitEx = Arr
    Exit Function
End If
If IgnoreDoubleDelmiters = True Then
    For Ndx = LBound(Delims) To UBound(Delims)
        N = InStr(1, InString, Delims(Ndx) & Delims(Ndx), vbTextCompare)
        Do Until N = 0
            InString = Replace(InString, Delims(Ndx) & Delims(Ndx), _
            Delims(Ndx))
            N = InStr(1, InString, Delims(Ndx) & Delims(Ndx), _
            vbTextCompare)
        Loop
    Next Ndx
End If


ReDim Arr(1 To Len(InString))
For Ndx = LBound(Delims) To UBound(Delims)
    InString = Replace(InString, Delims(Ndx), Chr(1))
Next Ndx
Arr = Split(InString, Chr(1))
SplitEx = Arr
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another VBA solution using nested loops

```
Option Explicit
Sub convertToList()
    Dim r As Range, c As Range, v, w, x, vres
    Dim i As Long
    Dim col As Collection

'Data in column A
With ActiveSheet
    Set r = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

Set col = New Collection
For Each c In r
    v = Split(c, ",")
    For Each w In v
        x = Split(w, "-")
            For i = x(LBound(x)) To x(UBound(x))
                col.Add i
            Next i
    Next w
Next c

ReDim vres(1 To col.Count, 1 To 1)
i = 0
For Each v In col
    i = i + 1
    vres(i, 1) = v
Next v

With r.Offset(0, 1).Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vres))
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vres
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi what if i wanted to do this same thing except with alphanumeric values.

Example, I want to expand the values in this first column into the second.

1. ```
   A411-A414
   A4150-A4153
   A4159
   A4181
   A4189
   A419
   A427
   A5601-A5602
   A5611
   D65
   D700-D704
   D708-D709
   D7289
   ```
  2.

```
A411
A412
A413
A414
A4150
A4151
A4152
A4153
A4159
A4181
A4189
A419
A427
A5601
A5602
A5611
D65
D700
D701
D702
D703
D704
D708
D709
D7289
```

Comment: Hey Obaid, could you structure the text into your answer so the external links aren't necessary?

Answer (score -1):

You could use a nested for loop:

```
f = """
     3074
88, 3074
1935, 3478-3480
3074, 3478-3479
27015-27030, 27036-27037
4380, 27000-27031, 27036 """

l = []
for x in f.split('\n'):
    for y in x.split(','):
        l += [z.strip() for z in y.split('-')]

for x in l:
    print(x)
>>
3074
88
3074
1935
3478
3480
3074
3478
3479
27015
27030
27036
27037
4380
27000
27031
27036
```

Of course, if this is a file, use

```
with open("filename.txt") as f:
    l = []
    for row in f:
        for y in x.split(','):
            l += [z.strip() for z in y.split('-')]
```

Comment: Not the expected output though.